# Sort excel worksheet using python

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I have an excel sheet like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1807.png]

I would like to output the data into an excel file like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8tWY.png]

Basically, for the common elements in column 2,3,4, I want to contacenate the values in the 5th column.

Please suggest, how could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to approach an issue like this is exporting the spreadsheet to CSV first, in order to help ensure that it imports correctly into Python.

Using a defaultdict, you can create a dictionary that has unique keys and then iterate through lines adding the final column's values to a list.

Finally you can write it back out to a CSV format:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

with open("in_file.csv") as f:
    header = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split(",")
        key = ",".join(cols[0:4])
        results[key].append(cols[4])

with open("out_file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(header)
    for k, v in results.iteritems():
        line = '{},"{}",\n'.format(k, ", ".join(v))
        f.write(line)
```